# What kind of base is this?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I've seen this layout a lot recently.

Does anyone know it's name or if there is any particular strategy for attacking it?

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a ["how do I attack this base" question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10661/185203)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen this base before, I'd say it is a war base, because his storages are on the outer part of his base & his TH and Clan Castle are in the middle. I would go in with (200 army cap) 4 Dragons, 12 Wizards, 10 Giants, 4 Wallbreakers, 8 Archers, and 6 Barbarians.
Amusing LV.3 Spell factory, 2 health potions and 1 rage potion

Attacking from South-West send in the 10 Giants first as the mortar's shell hits the ground send in 2 wallbreakers to get through the outer wall, Place the first Health Potion, then Spawn the Dragons followed by the Barbs, Archers, & Wizards. when they take out the 2nd D.Elixer drill spawn the other 2 wallbreakers. Use the Rage spell tward where the dragons are attacking and keep the health potion near the Wizards and Giants.

Answer (score -4):

Full Dragons in a line from the South west 3 rage spells for each air defense

Comment: While this technically answers the question, it does so extremely poorly.  *Why* would you use those units?  From that location?  Why use rage spells?  Those are critical for this to actually answer the question.